# Typescript dynamic import in Angular Formly

Tags: angular, import, angular-formly

I'm using formly to generate forms based on json schema.
I need to send a http request for some field options.

JSON :

```
{
    "key": "ReportCode",
    "type": "select",
    "className": "form-group dropdown-children",
    "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Report Code",
        "options": [],
        "httpLookUp": "true",
        "controllerPath": "app/controllers/report-management/report-controller",
        "controller": "ReportController",
        "method": "getReportCodeList",
        "valueProp": "Key",
        "labelProp": "Key",
        "required": true
    }
}
```

And i need to do this :

```
import(field.templateOptions.controllerPath).then((data: any) => {...
```

But it's not working.

This is working :

```
import('app/controllers/report-management/report-controller').then((data: any) => {...
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution :

```
import(`app/controllers/${field.templateOptions.controllerPath}`)
```